# Magento 1.9: Skip Shipping Method for all countrries

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I don't want to show the shipping method in the checkout page if customer select any country then shipping method does not change its only show the default value or anything I don't want to charge the customer for shipping

Comment: you can use freeshipping if you dont want to charge

Comment: free shipping is not working if change the country its show  Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make neccessary changes in your shipping address.

Comment: free shipping is only work for pakistan if change the country then its show the error also Ship to Applicable Countries set to all allowed countries

Comment: https://meetanshi.d.pr/q0M6Nn please check this setting

Comment: http://prntscr.com/p131c1 please check

Comment: it will show the free shipping in frontend or not?

Comment: yes its only show for one country if i change then it will not show

Comment: are you using any one step checkout extension?

Comment: http://m1d1.meetanshi.com/order-verification/apple-iphone-x.html please add product to cart and check in this site it will working fine for all the country

Comment: yes im using the theme checkout page

Comment: can you please check with default magento checkout

Comment: http://m1d1.meetanshi.com yes its working fine my default checkout page is not working

Comment: some issue in that checkout , else its 100% working with default magneto

Comment: any other way to asign using programming code free shipping

Comment: can you give me your site url

Comment: it need login details to access the site

Comment: you are using one step checkout extesnion

Comment: https://magento-314443-976598.cloudwaysapps.com/ please check on this link

Comment: in this example shipping method is display

Comment: but for uniworthdress shipping method is not displat

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98263/discussion-on-question-by-imran-bashir-magento-1-9-skip-shipping-method-for-all).

Comment: drops.meetanshi.com/q0M6Nn please check this setting